# How to get user name after authentication?

Tags: django, apache, authentication, ldap

I built a website using Django and Apache. I have Apache LDAP authentication. How do I get the username after the user authenticate to the website? I want to get the username and represents it.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! When you ask a question you should give the essential code related to that question you've tried so far.

Comment: I didn't try any thing, I don't know how to do that

Comment: Are you using [django-auth-ldap](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/users.html)?

Comment: No i am using Apache mod_auth_ldap

Comment: My authentication look like that http://cdn.freshdesk.com/data/helpdesk/attachments/production/4003603482/original/image001_png.png?1403051811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're using Apache LDAP Authentication. If you use `mod_auth_ldap`, see the docs here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_ldap.html#frontpage. If you use 
 `mod_authnz_ldap` see the docs here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#exposed.

What the docs tell is that, when the user is authenticated Apache sets environment variable, that can be accessed from CGI script. Variable name varies depending on the version you use. Though Python uses WSGI, you should still try to get the variable as it's environment variable and should be accessible anyway.

In python to get access to environment variable:

```
import os
username=os.getenv["REMOTE_USER"] #will return variable value or None
if username:
    pass
    #process username here
```

See docs on this function here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.getenv

You can try to use this directly in your Python code where you expect the username. Or better use this code in `wsgi.py` in your Django project and if `username` is available add special header with its value, so that it will be available inside Django in `request` passed to Django views. But remember to strip that header before adding it, so if a malicious user forges the header it doesn't affect your app. For more information on this see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/.

Edit: Btw, there's a "How-to" for `REMOTE_USER`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/auth-remote-user/

Edit: If you don't have any requirements for performing authentication with Apache, you might want to perform authentication in Django app directly, see: https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/ and in example https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/901/.

Comment: I checked the environment variables (advanced system settings > environment variables > and i didn't see remote user variable

Comment: It's not global environment variable. It's set by Apache inside the process after the particular user gets authenticated and therefore is available only in that process and its child processes. Also, to make it available you might need to change some Apache settings, see the links I provided for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much i success!!

Comment: Glad, that I was able to help you. )

Comment: @user5738816, updated the answer with link I stumbled upon: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/auth-remote-user/.

Comment: This did not work for me, `request.META['REMOTE_USER']` from the docs in the edit of the post did though.